# Polarization of Gravitational Waves Emitted by Binaries

Tags: gravitational-waves

Are the gravitational waves emitted by binary masses linearly or circularly polarized?

Is there a relationship between the binary rotation axis and the polarization?

Does this change during an inspiral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polarization depends on the relative orientation between the line of sight and the orbital plane of the binary (the *inclination angle* $\iota$). To leading order in $v/c$, where $v$ is the orbital velocity, the two polarizations $h_+$ and $h_\times$ are related to the inclination $\iota$ by
\begin{eqnarray}
h_+ &\propto& \frac{1 + \cos^2 \iota}{4} \\
h_\times &\propto& \cos \iota
\end{eqnarray}
up to factors which don't depend on the polarization.

For binaries with spin components not aligned with the orbital angular momentum, the binary will *precess*, and therefore in general the inclination angle and therefore the polarization will change with time.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. Do you have a good reference where I can read more about this?

Comment: @alessandro There are many references -- Maggiore's two volume book on gravitational waves is an excellent reference (I think this is in vol 1). Another reference is the 1994 classic paper by Cutler and Flanagan setting out the theoretical foundations of LIGO data analysis for compact binary mergers: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9402014.pdf. Search for the terms "inclination" and "precess" in that paper. Both of those sources also have plenty of references to other literature.

Answer (score 0):

A binary observed "face on" along its orbital axis will be seen to emit the equivalent of circularly polarised gravitational waves. That is, by analogy with electromagnetic waves, the gravitational waves emitted in that direction can be decomposed into an equal amplitude mixture of the two orthogonal wave polarisations (plus and cross), with a phase delay of $\pi/2$ between them

In contrast, an "edge-on" binary, observed along its orbital plane will be observed to emit "linearly polarised" gravitational waves consisting only of the plus polarisation.

If the binary is observed at other angles then the waves could be represented as an elliptical polarisation.