# Can either of LISA, NanoGrav or LIGO measure the polarization of gravitational wave background (GWB)?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravitational-waves, cosmological-inflation, gravitational-wave-detectors

Polarization in GWB should carry as much important information as in CMB. However, I've done some superfluous literature research and found little discussion. Is there any planned project for measuring the polarization? Or is there a method to extract the information from existing experiments?

Comment: They _do_ carry a lot of importance. There are discussions of polarization, in fact in a vast majority of literature. See for instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10194. For polarization in GW170814, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01193. However, most of the papers focus on inference and the parameter estimation aspects, so I wouldn't be surprised if explicit mention of this was left out.

Comment: @VaibhavK Thank you very much for the reference!

Comment: Note that there has been no actual detection of the primordial gravitational wave background.

Comment: @TimRiasTim Check NanoGrav 15-year dataset, GWB has been confirmed this year. It's more likely to have an astrophysical origin(SMBHB) though, not too exciting for new physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General Relativity predicts two polarization states for GWs, often referred to as "plus" and "cross".  Both of these are tensor-transverse (TT) modes.  In theories that extend GR there could be additional scalar-transverse (ST), scalar-longitudinal (SL), and/or vector-longitudinal (VL) modes.  Looking for non-GR modes is one way to test GR.  If GR is correct, then we shouldn't find any additional modes.

Each mode leads to a different overlap reduction function (ORF) for the correlations between detectors.  For pulsar timing arrays the TT ORF is the Hellings-Downs curve, which NANOGrav and other PTAs showed evidence for in June 2023.[image: Figure from NANOGrav's 15yr stochastic background analysis paper showing the Hellings-Downs curve for pulsar correlations predicted by GR compared to the measured correlations from data.]
This figure from [NANOGrav's 15yr stochastic background analysis paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.16213) shows the Hellings-Downs curve for pulsar correlations from the TT modes of GR compared to the measured correlations from data.

One way to detect additional polarization modes is to look for deviations from the Hellings-Downs curve (although other effects cause deviations too).

NANOGrav carried out that analysis [using their 12.5yr dataset in 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14706).  The Hellings-Downs correlation pattern wasn't measured back then so the results aren't conclusive.  In the past few days an [independent group has used NANOGrav's publicly available data to look for non-GR modes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.11238), and [NANOGrav released their findings using their most recent dataset as well](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.12138).  Both analyses found the GR model (with only TT modes) to be marginally preferred over other models.  One would need more data to get a more constraining measurement of the correlation pattern to put stronger limits on the existence of non-TT polarization modes.

The same group has previously analyzed other public PTA data sets from NANOGrav, PPTA, and IPTA, looking for additional polarization modes.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer. For the TT mode, there are still two polarizations left, namely, the plus and cross polarization. They’re in principle distinguishable. Can the existing experiments distinguish these two polarizations? Do they carry important physical information from astrophysical and cosmological sources?

Comment: Yes. There are several questions related to GW polarization (for example, this answer about BBH polarization https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/629238/47594).  But I don't think any specifically address GWB.

Comment: If you can't find the answer after a quick search of existing questions, you should ask this follow-up as a new question, and possibly link back to this original question as a reference.